# Partial Differentiation - how to know Which Variables to Hold Constant? (Dependent Variables)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm teaching myself university-level calculus, and have run into a few problems with partial differentiation that I thought I understood. Mostly to do with differentiating functions whereby the variables are not independent, but dependent with respect to each other. I have a theory on the answer, so I'll lay out the problem and then my idea.

Firstly, the **tl;dr** Q - "When calculating $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}$, how do you decide whether variables that are in some way dependent on/'connected to' $x$ are free to be left as constants, or must change when $x$ does?"

My apologies for the length, and for asking such a basic question, but I'm very new at this.

**Example 1**

Let's say you had this question I created:

$ w = x^2 + z^2 $,  whereby, $z = x^2 + y^2$. Find $ \frac{\partial{w}}{\partial {x}} $

This sort of Q, with *no other qualifying info*, seems perfectly familiar and normal. As to solving it - well, clearly z is dependent on x, and originally I thought this should be straightforward to handle, via using the multivariable chain rule:

$ \frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{x}} = \frac{\partial{x^2}}{\partial{x}} \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{x}} + \frac{\partial{z^2}}{\partial{z}} \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}
$

And, critically of course, because $y$ and thus $ y^2$ is 'of course' (I'll reference this later) considered a constant:

$
\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{x}} = 2x + 2z (2x)
$

**Example 2**

But, now consider the example given in this pdf [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02-multivariable-calculus-fall-2007/readings/non_ind_variable.pdf), on dependent vs independent variables in partial differentiation. Everything is the same as Ex.1 except $y^2$ is now part of the function defining $w$:

$w = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ (1), whereby $ z = x^2 + y^2 $ (2), and the author explores again calculating $ \frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{x}}$.

The author explains that whilst it's again perfectly valid to consider $y$ as constant, and to calculate $\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{x}}$ thusly (i.e. similarly to Ex.1), there's also a **second** scenario that is also perfectly valid to consider, whereby $y$ is not constant but rather $z$ is. In fact one **must** specify whether they want $\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{x}}$ calculated within the first case or this second.

In this second case, when $x$ changes, $y$ changes oppositely to 'absorb' the potential increase/decrease in $z$. So, as $x$ changes, $z$ remains a constant but now $y$ changes, and is a function of $x$.

I feel like I understand this, and why one can, and in fact must, consider these two different scenarios. Firstly via the specific, geometric explanation given in the pdf - but more generally, too: in order for equation **(2) to hold**, when $x$ changes *something* within that equation must also change. But simply, it just doesn't have to be $z$ - it could be that one (or more) of the other, non-$x$ variables defining it might change. That's valid, and one must choose which scenario they want to consider.

This is in contrast to say if actually (2) was $ z = x^2 $, and so for (2) to now hold when $x$ changes, $z$ now has no choice but to change, too.

And I think that all this is just something I hadn't been told about before, thinking that when calculating partials, all other variables that don't solely depend on $x$ are, 'by default', always held constant.

---

The **question** I'm stuck on however and come to now after that unfortunately long intro, is this:

*Why in Ex.2 are we allowed to also consider the case where $y$ is not a constant, and, in fact, *must* specify which case we're interested in, but we must always think of $y$ as constant, in Ex.1?*

Here's my theory:

"It actually is perfectly fine in Ex. 1 to consider the case of $y$ as changing due to $x$ and $z$ instead as constant, but then $\frac{\partial{z^2}}{\partial{x}} = \frac{\partial{z^2}}{\partial{z}}\cdot \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}} = 2z \cdot 0 = 0$, and thus $\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial{x}} = \frac{\partial{x^2}}{\partial{x}} + 0$.  This then is a largely trivial case, and thus as a notational convention, instead of the question mentioning 'two separate cases' and specificying it wants you to pursue the one where $y$ is constant, as a convention you're just expected to assume $y$ is constant.
**Also, because** $y$ appears nowhere else but within $z$, the additional effects on the system of $y$ changing are nil.

And so actually my original answer for Ex.1, which came from automatically assuming $y$ is constant, is in fact correct, and you're just supposed to ignore the second case.

**If** however $y$ is mentioned somewhere else in the system (e.g. if $w= x^2 + y^2 + z^2$, or say $y$ were a parameter of some other variable in the system, not just of $z$), and is designated to be the one changing (not $z$), then $\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}} = 0$ still, **but** now $y$ changing with $x$ very much would have additional effects elsewhere and so this case is non-trivial, and so you must specify if you are in the case where $y$ is changing and $z$ isn't, or vice versa."

---

So, that's my question and my theory - I hope it all made sense, and certainly apologies for the extreme length, I just wanted to lay it all out as clearly as I could, because I'm new to this. And apologies for what must be a very basic question.

What are your thoughts? Further and importantly, is there some bigger picture that sums up how to handle such cases of interdependent variables (I'm assuming so)? Indeed, I understand that even with just a handful of variables, depending on how they're connected, a dependent chain/network of partials could get very complicated very vast, so I'd be keen to understand the general rule of how to handle things.

Many thanks, indeed!